# how to display the following images?

Tags: flask, keras

first I defined two functions in my app.py file as follows:

```
senti=["furious","angry","angry0","Indiferent","happy","enthusiastic","Euphoric"]

def predict(text):
    seqs = tok.texts_to_sequences([text])
    print(text)
    word_index = tok.word_index
    print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))
    sequence_pred = sequence.pad_sequences(seqs, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
    print(sequence_pred)
    prediction = model.predict(sequence_pred)
    print(prediction)
    return senti[np.argmax(prediction[0])]
```

Here I get the values of  image_url that is the path of my image as follows:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    senti=["furious","angry","angry0","Indiferent","happy","enthusiastic","Euphoric"]
    images=['static/angry.jpg','static/angry.jpg','static/angry.jpg','static/smile.jpg','static/smile.jpg','static/smile.jpg','static/smile.jpg']
    lookup_keys = dict(zip(senti, images))
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        q=request.form['querytext']
        prediction=predict(q)
        image_path = lookup_keys[prediction] # get the path
        print(image_path)
        return render_template("result.html",
                               prediction=prediction,
                               text=q,
                               image_url=image_path)
    return render_template("main.html")
```

then depending of the result I would like to display and image I am just using two smile.jpg and angry.jpg that are contained in the static folder, 
after that I render my template called: "result.html"

this file contains the following tags to show me the text and prediction as follows:

```
<h3>{{text}} </br> <button class="button-primary">{{prediction}}</button></h3>
```

Everything works well until this point I want to show the image dynamically I tried:

```
<h3>{{image_url}}<td><img src={image_url} alt=""></td></h3>
```

However is not displaying nothing, If I put the following tag:

```
<td><img src='static/angry.jpg' alt=""></td>
```

the image is being displayed with any problems I would like to appreciate support to modify the tag of above to display the image dinamically I mean this part:

```
 <td><img src='static/angry.jpg' alt=""></td>
```

I would like to change dinamically this string 'static/angry.jpg' with the value of my variable called image_url, I am a begginer using flask so I am not sure how to use this value, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sure your image_url path is fine then:

```
<td><img src="{{image_url}}" alt=""></td>
```